# Get version of used library with Stack

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell project that's built with Stack.

In my Cabal file, I've added a bunch of libraries as dependencies, [tls](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls) for example.

**Is there a command to get the version of a specific library used in my project?**

I know from `stack.yaml` that I'm using the resolver `lts-14.16`. I could therefore visit [the page of this LTS on Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.16) and look for the version number of my library there. But I hope there's a more straightforward way, using the command line, to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `stack ls dependencies`

This command lists the dependencies and their versions of the current project, as mentioned [here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#listing-dependencies). It produces output like the following:

```
StateVar 1.2
aeson 1.4.6.0
ansi-terminal 0.9.1
array 0.5.3.0
asn1-encoding 0.9.6
asn1-parse 0.9.5
asn1-types 0.3.3
async 2.2.2
attoparsec 0.13.2.3
base 4.12.0.0
```

Use [`grep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to pick the library you're interested in:

```
stack ls dependencies 2>/dev/null | grep "^tls"
```

We use `2>/dev/null` to silence any warnings that Stack might produce regarding the project.

If you want to go further and visualize your dependencies, as a graph or tree for instance, use [`stack dot`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/dependency_visualization/).